# Problems with "sh -c" not accepting extra arguments, UNIX, using execve()

Tags: bash, unix, arguments, sh, execve

I'm attempting to find out how to use `sh -c`  or `bash -c` properly.

I can easily run a simple command like  `"sh -c ls"` without arguments.

The problem comes when I'm trying to add in arguments.
To do `ls -ltga`, I've had to do:

```
sh -c "ls -ltga"
```

This wouldn't be a big issue, except I'm attempting to write my own small shell program,
and when I use `execve` I try:

```
Argument #:  string
         0:  sh
         1:  -c
         2:  "ls
         3:  -ltga"
```

And it gives me an error, saying that it reached an EOF before finding the next `'"'`

I've also tried:

```
         0:  sh
         1:  -c
         2:  "ls -ltga"
```

and it returned to me saying that it couldn't find the file/script named `"ls -ltga"`

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried *2: ls -ltga*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't put quotes inside arguments of `execve()`. It should be called like this:

```
char *args = { "sh", "-c", "ls -ltga", 0};
execve("/bin/sh", args);
```

The first argument to `execve()` must be the path to the executable (usually a full path).

Comment: When I don't use the quotes, all of the arguments for the command get ignored, both inside the shell, and with execve.

Comment: @StefanZuefeldt: The shell uses quotes to "group" the arguments. `execve` doesn't need that; the grouping is handled implicitly, by each argument being a separate array element. Specifying `"ls -ltga"` as one of the arguments via `execve` is like specifying `'"ls -ltga"'` as one of the arguments inside the shell.

Comment: While technically this was the answer that solved my issue, every answer here was extremely helpful!  Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0):

The notation the shell expects is `sh -c "command plus arguments"`.  So, what you're doing as a 'workaround' is in fact what the shell demands.

The alternative is to use `execvp()` to run `ls`:

```
char *args[] = { "ls", "-lgta", 0 };
execvp(args[0], args);
fprintf(stderr, "Oops: failed to find 'ls'\n");
exit(1);
```

---

> I also need to be able to run commands with regular expressions, such as `"rm *.c"`, but that fails to run within `execve()` (most cases), so I am attempting to work around that failure by passing the entire command set to "sh -c" instead. Any ideas?

If you want metacharacter expansion, you have to invoke the shell to do it (or write equivalent code to do it - which is possible and not too dreadfully hard to do with standard POSIX functions).

To run '`rm *.c`', use:

```
char *args[] = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "rm *.c", 0 };
execv(args[0], args);
```

Or, if you have an environment you need to pass specifically (I assume it is pointed to by `envp`):

```
char *args[] = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "rm *.c", 0 };
execve(args[0], args, envp);
```

Don't forget the error handling after the `exec*` function call; it can fail.

Comment: I also need to be able to run commands with regular expressions, such as  "rm *.c", but that fails to run within execve (most cases), so I am attempting to work around that failure by passing the entire command set to  "sh -c" instead.  Any ideas?